# C - Why is the answer 0.00000, when I try enter 3 numbers for the sum and average?

Tags: c, integer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

float num1 = 0;
float num2 = 0;
float num3 = 0;
float sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
float average = sum / 3;


printf("Enter three numbers:\n"); //Enter three floats
scanf("%f %f %f", &num1, &num2, &num3); //Assign to num1, num2, num3 

printf("The sum of these three numbers is %f.\n", sum);//Print sum
printf("The average of these numbers is %f.\n", average);//Print average

}
```

This is what is displayed.

```
Enter three numbers:

12.0

10.0

12.0

The sum of these three numbers is 0.000000.

The average of these numbers is 0.000000.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C programs execute from top to bottom one instruction at a time. You have calculated `sum` and `average` before accepting the numbers. This evaluated to `sum=0` and `average=0` because all three numbers were 0.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float num1,num2,num3,sum,average;

    printf("Enter three numbers:\n"); //Enter three floats
    scanf("%f %f %f", &num1, &num2, &num3); //Assign to num1, num2, num3 

    sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
    average = sum / 3;

    printf("The sum of these three numbers is %f.\n", sum);//Print sum
    printf("The average of these numbers is %f.\n", average);//Print average
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Remember that C runs from top to bottom in a function without loops or conditionals.

You created num1, num2, and num3, as 0 each, and found their sum and average *before* inputting the numbers.

Do as follows:

```
float num1 = 0;
float num2 = 0;
float num3 = 0;
float sum = 0;
float average = 0;   

printf("Enter three numbers:\n"); //Enter three floats
scanf("%f %f %f", &num1, &num2, &num3); //Assign to num1, num2, num3 

sum = num1 + num2 + num3; //calculate
average = sum / 3;

printf("The sum of these three numbers is %f.\n", sum);//Print sum

printf("The average of these numbers is %f.\n", average);//Print average
```

Answer (score 5):

You seem to misunderstand the usage of variable definition. These:

```
float num1 = 0;
float num2 = 0;
float num3 = 0;
float sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
float average = sum / 3;
```

do not define the way the `sum` will be computed after the reading is done, but actually use these values and calculate the `sum` and `average` to be `0` before the program calls first `scanf`.

```
scanf("%f %f %f", &num1, &num2, &num3);
sum = num1 + num2 + num3;                     // <-- place it here
average = sum / 3;
```